# How do I get a text file to be a part of my build?

Tags: vb.net, build

I wrote a program that reads from text files and can create them to load and save data.  I have a few files that are the "default" data that are loaded as soon as the program start.  The files are loaded by a static reference.  My code runs fine before I publish it, but obviously when I publish it, the static references no longer work.  I don't know how to add the default data to the build as distinct text files so that I can still reference it after the build.

I imagine being able to build the program and have some sort of folder that accompanies the executable with the default data files in them that I can easily reference, but I don't know how to do that (or if there is a better way).

Below is the start of the code I use to read from the file.  Currently, the default data's file name is passed statically into the sub and is used to identify the file to read from, so I'd like to have a published file that I can do the same thing with.

```
Try
    Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(FileName)
    Dim strLine As String = ""

    Do Until sr.EndOfStream
        strLine = sr.ReadLine
        'Code that interprets the data in the file
```

Note: I've tried adding the files as "Resources" but I can't seem to reference the file as a text file; I can only retrieve the massive wall of text contained within the document which won't work with the above code (unless of course I'm missing something).

If you could clarify:

1. How do I add a file to a build so that I can still access it
   collectively by a file name?
2. How will my code reference the files (e.g. by
   "My.Resources.filename"?) in the final build?

Comment: Is it just a text file you need to access that's going to live in the the same directory tree as your app?  You can add a folder within your solution.  Add a text file to that folder and set the "Copy to Output Directory" to one of the "Copy" options.  It will copy the file from the project into the directory on build.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: How are you deploying your application ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add the file to the build as either a content file or an embedded resource.

For a content file, set the Build Action of the file to 'content', and Copy to Output Directory to 'Copy Always' in the file properties. You can then access the file like this:

```
FileName = Application.StartupPath() = + FileName
Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(FileName)
...
```

To embed the file as a resource you have to set the Build Action of the file to 'Embedded Resource' and Copy to Output Directory to false.
This [Microsoft support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319291) has a walkthough about accessing embedded resources. The code would be something like this:

```
Dim sr As StreamReader
Dim thisAssembly As Assembly
thisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
sr = New StreamReader(thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("NameSpace." + FileName))

Dim strLine As String = ""
Do Until sr.EndOfStream
    strLine = sr.ReadLine
    'Code that interprets the data in the file
    ...
```

Replace `NameSpace` with the namespace of your application (Project Properties -> Application -> root namespace)

You also have to add `Imports System.Reflection` at the top of your code file.

Using an embedded resource has the advantage of less files to manage, and you don't have to keep track of paths.

Comment: I added a folder as tcshao suggested and then reworked your code for adding a content file a little bit to get my solution to work!  Thank you very much!